# TensorFlow equivalent to array_A[:, 0]

Tags: python, tensorflow

TensorFlow equivalent to:

```
array_A[:, 0]
```

Get item in the first column for all rows.

Comment: tf.slice(input_, begin, size, name=None)

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Tensorflow, you should just be able to write tensor_A[:, 0] .

In older versions, you can use tf.slice.